# Returning multiple matches with vlookup, offset, match

Tags: excel, match, offset, vlookup

Hi everyone I have a table of data that contains multiple matches when using vlookup. I was following a lesson that used a combination of vlookup, offset and match to return the second match. However, I am stuck in how I should return the third match.

I know index and match is probably better for this, but I was unable to follow how those expressions work.

My lookup table has 3 columns of data. The first column is a name that repeats with different data in columns 2 and 3. I want to lookup by name and return the content of column 2 and 3.

My expression for the first match is:

```
Column 2:=VLOOKUP($A3,Sheet1!$J$2:$L$4554,2,FALSE)
Column 3:=VLOOKUP($A3,Sheet1!$J$2:$L$4554,3,FALSE)
```

The expression for the second match is:

Column 2 data:

```
=VLOOKUP($A3,OFFSET(Sheet1!$J$2,MATCH($A3,Sheet1!$J$2:$J$4554,0),0,4600,3),2,FALSE)
```

Column 3 data:

```
=VLOOKUP($A3,OFFSET(Sheet1!$J$2,MATCH($A3,Sheet1!$J$2:$J$4554,0),0,4600,3),3,FALSE)
```

How can I use a similar formula to offset for the 3rd match and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Array Formula Requires **CTRL+Shift+Enter** instead of normal enter

=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$J$2:$L$10,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$J$2:$J$10=$A$3,ROW(Sheet1!$J$2:$L$10)-MIN(ROW(Sheet1!$J$2:$L$10))+1),ROWS($1:1)),COLUMNS($A:B)),"")